# Why does the position of a ScrollView target not initialized automatically when using .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to display 4 images within a scroll view and be able to swipe through them. The problem is that when the sheet loads the cards appear off-centre. I think it has to do with the way the value is initialized within the scrollview because when you swipe to see the other images all of them get positioned correctly. [off centre-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6upUA.png)[-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWXsR.png)

I have an enum defining the values for each tournament but for this example I'm only using the rawvalue.

Within the view I have a couple properties determine which image is showing.

```
    @State var id: Tournament? //image displayed
    let tournaments: [Tournament] = [.roland, .wimbledon, .us, .ao] //array to call the images
```

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            HStack(){
                                ForEach (tournaments, id: \.self){ tournament in
                                    Image("\(tournament.rawValue)-court") //image that appears off centre when first displayed
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                                        
                                        .scrollTransition (topLeading: .interactive, bottomTrailing: .interactive, axis: .horizontal) { effect, phase in effect
                                                .scaleEffect(1 - (abs(phase.value)/5))
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .scrollTargetLayout()
                            
                        }
                        

                        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                        .scrollPosition(id: $id, anchor: .center)
                        .safeAreaPadding()
```

I have tried initializing the value using init, but it doesn't work because `tournament` within the  `ForEach` is a let constant.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], something I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the issue.